# Kernel configuration for the computer and its installation in Linux

Tags: help-files

I love OS Linux Mint Cinnamon. I've put Linux on their hardware. I wanted to find the one Linux distribution that will use my PC at full capacity. It is necessary to remove all the excess out of the Linux kernel. Maybe there is a volunteer who taught me to configure the kernel is at a specific computer.I wanted to find the one Linux distribution that will use my PC at full capacity. It is necessary to remove all the excess out of the Linux kernel.I love Linux. I respect Linus Torvalds. I want to set it up the core of a personal computer.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with other linux flavors, but it must be similar with Mint.

You need to have **gcc,make,automake** and all of its dependencies installed or you will fail at step 1.

First download the kernel from kernel.org and extract it.
attach all devices you ever want to use, or have to recompile later.

Get into the folder you extracted the kernel to

```
make localmodconfig
```

- Update current config disabling modules not loaded

```
make -j 4
make -j 4 modules
make -j 4 modules_install
make install
```

reboot.